# Combined probability density of two distributions

Tags: probability

I want to sample a direction from a distribution that is 
composed of a Gaussian and a semicircular region. Namely, I first 
choose an angle $\theta$ using a Gaussian pdf $g(\theta)$
$$
g(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\, e^{-\frac{\theta^2}{2 \sigma^2}}
$$
Then I perturb this angle uniformly within some cone (semicirucular region)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC8ur.png)
$$
p(\theta) = \sin{\theta} (1-\cos{\theta_{\max}})
$$
where $\theta_{\max}$ is the maximum aperture angle.

I want to compute the combined probability density function 
(the convolution of $g(\theta)$ and $p(\theta)$).

Is there a closed-form approximation to this?

Comment: Is $p(\theta)$ supposed to be a probability density function?  If so, I wouldn't call it "uniform". ${}\qquad{}$